# Time series horizontal bar chart for running queries visualization

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I need to build a time series horizontal bar chart that looks something like this. Each bar represents a query running on the cluster. The length of the bar represents the duration. Each query has start time and end time. Multiple queries can have either same start time or end time or both. Queries may be running in parallel.

[image]

I am using highcharts/highstocks charting library,  wondering what kind of Highchart config I need to use to accomplish it. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a **columnrange** series. Here you have an example of it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6bu8gtaw
It is hardcoded for now, you can edit it and adjust to your requirements.

All used API properties you can find here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true,
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#d3d3d3'
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    layout: 'vertical'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0.1,
      grouping: false,
      pointWidth: 6,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: null
  },

  xAxis: {
    visible: false,
    reversed: false,
    min: -3,
    max: 7
  },

  yAxis: {
    opposite: true,
    min: -3,
    max: 18
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [0, 10, 13]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [1, 2, 5]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [1, 6, 9]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [1, 12, 16]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [2, 3, 7]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [2, 7, 12]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [3, 0, 4]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [3, 5, 10]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [3, 10, 14]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [3, 16, 18]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [4, 0, 5]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [4, 6, 11]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [4, 11, 15]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [4, 16, 18]
    ]
  }]

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using xrange chart, that seem to fit the bill https://www.highcharts.com/demo/x-range.

Comment: Yes, xrange is very similar, I was wondering whether to create a columnrange or xrange, but I ended up with columnrange ;) let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your time.